# Applying roles to an admin sub-menu (eg Appearance -> Menus)

Tags: permissions, capabilities, user-roles

Long time lurker, but first time poster. I've searched Google extensively and just can't seem to come up with an answer on this problem.

I use Justin Tadlock's excellent 'Members' plugin for roles and permissions on several client installations of WP. I've recently deployed a theme where the client should only have access to the Appearance -> Menus item, but none of the others sub-items in the Appearance menu of the admin.

When enabled, the role 'edit_theme_options' enables the user to access 'Themes', 'Widgets', and 'Menus'. How would I go about filtering the submenu so that if the role 'edit_custom_menus' is assigned, the 'Menus' link will show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further searching and after discovering the $submenu global variable, I've managed to find a helpful tutorial on [removing sub-menus from the WordPress admin](https://kapilchugh.wordpress.com/2010/06/07/wordpress-disableremove-menu-submenus/).

I'll post with code when I get a full solution implemented and integrated with the plugin.

Comment: some feedback at least would be nice so to know if this question is answered or not :)

Comment: Something to note is that WordPress partially determines the required caps to view a page based on the capability set in the menu item, a filter on the admin_menu would allow you to update the appropriate array item with your desired cap... (i'll happily go into more detail if it's requested).

Answer (score 0):

I don't use plugin myself, so speaking theoretically. There are two parts to this:

1. Determine if user has role that can see menus. Plugin's documentation describes `current_user_has_role()` function for this.
2. Actually hiding menus if role doesn't fit. I don't have anything tested to offer, try this for starters: [How to remove menus in WordPress dashboard ( WpRecipes )](http://www.wprecipes.com/how-to-remove-menus-in-wordpress-dashboard)